# Comparing the lines in multiple txt files

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, file

I am writing a Python program to find and duplicate lines in txt files from a folder.

My folder structure is

```
f1--> review.txt
f2--> review.txt
f3--> review.txt
```

and so on (`f1` represent folder name)

I want to find which line came again in another txt file
for example if file "f1/review.txt" first line is `I want to eat an apple` then in which all other file `I want to eat an apple` came again. I want a more efficient way to do it. I am writing a lot of loops to do it and it is getting bigger

My approach till now (for two files)

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk('root'):
        for file in files:

            with open(os.path.join(root,file), "r") as auto:
                if file == "review.txt":
                    lines=auto.readlines()
                    for line in lines:
                            f=open("root/f1/review.txt","r")
                            src_lines=f.readlines()

                            for src_line in src_lines:


           src_sent=find_error(src_line,src_line_num+':    ')
                                   curr_sent=find_error(line,curr_file_num+':    ')


if src_sent==curr_sent:
       res.append([line_num])
```

EDIT
(can Please format above code)

txt file content if it helps in any way):

```
classes/CadenceMyProfileController1.cls:6:    Avoid really long classes (lines of code)
/data/public/pmd/repo/src/1/src/classes/CadenceMyProfileController1.cls:6:    Missing ApexDoc comment
/data/public/pmd/repo/src/1/src/classes/CadenceMyProfileController1.cls:6:    The class 'CadenceMyProfileController1' has a Standard Cyclomatic Complexity of 2 (Highest = 174).
/data/public/pmd/repo/src/1/src/classes/CadenceMyProfileController1.cls:6:    The class 'CadenceMyProfileController1' has a total cyclomatic complexity of 422 (highest 215).
/data/public/pmd/repo/src/1/src/classes/CadenceMyProfileController1.cls:6:    This class has too many public methods and attributes
/data/public/pmd/repo/src/1/src/classes/CadenceMyProfileController1.cls:7:    Avoid really long classes (lines of code)
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: You might wanna read your files in as a pandas series & then use this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: do you want to check for entire lines or words?

Comment: @MisterNox entire line (but I do wanna discard some part of that line)

Comment: @zabop its an entire line not a word so taking it into pandas won't be much effective.

Comment: could you add a short example with two of your files where this happens and what you want to change then. Then I am pretty sure I can give an example.

Comment: Alright. An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help us giving better answers.

Comment: @zabop  added my solution till now but it is for two files only

Comment: @MisterNox added solution for two files

Comment: Yeah, that's a good start. If you add file contents (not necessarily your real files but ones which are simple and reproduce the issue you are having), it'll be even better.

Comment: Main point: your readers should be able to run the whole thing, to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: @zabop added txt file content , it is same for all files just different lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219050/discussion-between-vaibhav-kumar-chaudhary-and-zabop).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it really is shorter than yours but you have to touch every line as you want to check if they are different so we have to go through all the lines. In my solution it checks every line of a file with all lines of others and changes the line to `"Changed"`.

But be careful with the invisible `"\n"` as this solution says they are different when one line is the last line in a file and the other is somewhere in the middle. If you need this to be stated as equal I can change that. Hope it helps in some kind of way:

```
def check_and_edit(file_path, path_list):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for path in path_list:
        with open(path, "r+") as f:
            target_lines = f.readlines()
            changes = False
            for i, target in enumerate(target_lines):
                if target in lines:
                    target_lines[i] = "Changed \n"
                    changes = True
            if changes:
                f.truncate(0)
                f.seek(0, 0)
                f.writelines(target_lines)

check_and_edit(file_path, path_list)
```